# I edit an excel file and the following error appears UserWarning: Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed warn(msg)

Tags: python, excel, typeerror, openpyxl

the excel document is ready, I just need to make some changes and save the pdf document

```
from win32com import client
import openpyxl
import datetime
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import DataBar, FormatObject

Previous_Date = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=2)
Previous_Date_f = Previous_Date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")


def date():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("09.xlsx", read_only=False, data_only=False, keep_links=True)
    ws = wb.active
    ws["B1"] = Previous_Date_f
    ws["B2"] = Previous_Date_f
    first = FormatObject(type='min')
    second = FormatObject(type='max')
    data_bar = DataBar(cfvo=[first, second], color="32CD32", showValue=None, minLength=None, maxLength=None)
    rule = Rule(type='dataBar', dataBar=data_bar)
    ws.conditional_formatting.add("F5:F52", rule)
    wb.save(filename='n09.xlsx')


def pdf():
    excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    sheets = excel.Workbooks.Open("../Desktop/new/n09.xlsx")
    work_sheets = sheets.Worksheets[0]
    work_sheets.PageSetup.Orientation = 2
    work_sheets.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, "../Desktop/new/n09.pdf")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    date()
    pdf()
```

gives the following errors

```
UserWarning: Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)
```

```
UserWarning: Conditional Formatting extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)
```

The code does not work perfectly.
It just has to convert the edited excel file to pdf.
Who knows how to fix the errors, please tell me.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a PyCharm error, do you know what library is raising the error?

Comment: openpyxl, because when I did it through another library, there were no such errors

Comment: Ok, I couldn't find the error before but now knowing it's openpyxl I'm linking a post that's popular and seems to address the specific error you're getting.

Comment: in your solution read_only = True and it works for reading and I'm modifying the file so it doesn't work